# Handling Null Safety Error When Accessing 'state' in Flutter Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, null-safety

I'm integrating Riverpod for state management in a Flutter application and have encountered a null safety error related to accessing the 'state' property. This issue arises within my code that aims to update an image, a feature critical for both web and mobile platforms. Here is the specific error message I received:

> "The property 'state' can't be unconditionally accessed because the
> receiver can be 'null'. Try making the access conditional (using '?.')
> or adding a null check to the target ('!')."

The error surfaces in the `_pickImage` method, specifically when attempting to update the state with a new image file. Below is the relevant portion of my code:

```
final pickedImageProvider = StateProvider<File?>((ref) => null);
final webImageProvider = StateProvider<Uint8List>((ref) => Uint8List(8));
final tapOffsetProvider = StateProvider<Offset?>((ref) => null);

class ProfileAppBar extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ProfileAppBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Future<void> _pickImage(BuildContext context) async {
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
      XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (image != null) {
        var selected = File(image.path);
        context.read(pickedImageProvider).state = selected;
      } else {
        print('No image has been picked ');
      }
    } else if (kIsWeb) {
      final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
      XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (image != null) {
        var f = await image.readAsBytes();
        context.read(webImageProvider).state = f;
        context.read(pickedImageProvider).state = File('a');
      } else {
        print('No image has been picked ');
      }
    } else {
      print('Something went wrong');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          ...   Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Tooltip(
                    message: 'Settings',
                    child: Semantics(
                      label: 'Pomodoro timer settings',
                      enabled: true,
                      readOnly: true,
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.settings_outlined,
                          color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                          size: 24,
                          semanticLabel: 'Pomodoro timer Settings',
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const Scaffold(),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                    onTapDown: (details) {
                      ref.read(tapOffsetProvider).state =
                          details.globalPosition;
                    },
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        final tapOffset = ref.watch(tapOffsetProvider).state;
                        if (tapOffset != null) {
                          showMenu(
                            position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
                              tapOffset!.dx - 150,
                              64,
                              tapOffset.dx ?? 0,
                              0,
                            ),
                            constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                              maxWidth: 600,
                            ),...
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

- How can I modify my _pickImage method to safely access and update the state without triggering the null safety error?
- Is there a recommended practice for handling conditional access or null checks in this context, especially considering the dual targets of web and mobile platforms?

I've attempted using conditional access operators like `?`. and null assertion operators like `!`, but I'm unsure of the best practice in this scenario.

Your insights and advice on addressing this null safety error effectively would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work fine! I see only one problem with the button:

```
IconButton(
onPressed: () {
  final tapOffset = ref.read(tapOffsetProvider); // `state` don't required
  if (tapOffset != null) {...}
```

In callbacks it is necessary to use `ref.read`.

---

To use your providers, just add `!` if you are sure the value is not `null` or use `?`.

```
final pickedImageProvider = StateProvider<File?>((ref) => null);

{
  File? pickedImage = ref.read(pickedImageProvider);
  File pickedImageNotNull = ref.read(pickedImageProvider)!;

  String? pickedImagePath = ref.read(pickedImageProvider)?.path;
  String pickedImagePathNotNull = ref.read(pickedImageProvider)!.path;
}
```

---

But really your problem is that you forgot to use the `.notifier` and are not correctly trying to access the state:

```
context.read(pickedImageProvider.notifier).state = selected;
context.read(webImageProvider.notifier).state = f;
context.read(pickedImageProvider.notifier).state = File('a');

// Or do it this way:
context.read(pickedImageProvider.notifier).update((_) => selected);
context.read(webImageProvider.notifier).update((_) => f);
context.read(pickedImageProvider.notifier).update((_) => File('a'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I appreciate your answer. Could you please guide me on where to add the following code snippet? `{
  File? pickedImage = ref.read(pickedImageProvider);
  File pickedImageNotNull = ref.read(pickedImageProvider)!;

  String? pickedImagePath = ref.read(pickedImageProvider)?.path;
  String pickedImagePathNotNull = ref.read(pickedImageProvider)!.path;
}` this is the error message: "Expected a method, getter, setter or operator declaration.
This appears to be incomplete code. Try removing it or completing it."

Comment: In all places where you use `context.read` or `context.watch` and `ref.watch` or `ref.read`